# task_pt_regs in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

```
/*
 * The below -8 is to reserve 8 bytes on top of the ring0 stack.
 * This is necessary to guarantee that the entire "struct pt_regs"
 * is accessible even if the CPU haven't stored the SS/ESP registers
 * on the stack (interrupt gate does not save these registers
 * when switching to the same priv ring).
 * Therefore beware: accessing the ss/esp fields of the
 * "struct pt_regs" is possible, but they may contain the
 * completely wrong values.
 */
#define task_pt_regs(task)                                             \
({                                                                     \
       struct pt_regs *__regs__;                                       \
       __regs__ = (struct pt_regs *)(KSTK_TOP(task_stack_page(task))-8); \
       __regs__ - 1;                                                   \
})
```

The code was copied from `linux3.4.5/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h`, my questions are:

1. About "reserve 8 bytes on top of the ring0 stack", could anybody show me
   the related code in kernel?
2. If "CPU haven't stored the SS/ESP register", how can `task_pt_regs` get the correct address of `pt_regs`?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. About "reserve 8 bytes on top of the ring0 stack", could anybody show me the related code in kernel?

The code you showed in your question reserves bytes for the process.When a process is created, its kernel stack is set up by the following call chain:

```
kernel 4.6
do_fork() -->
_do_fork() -->
    copy_process() -->
    copy_thread_tls() -->       arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c
        ... ...
        childregs = task_pt_regs(p);  //p is new process task_struct
                          //childregs point to new process pt_regs.
                          //This is where the new process reserved the space.
             ... ...
        *childregs = *current_pt_regs(); //Copy the pt_regs from parent process.
```

> 2. If "CPU haven't stored the SS/ESP register", how can task_pt_regs get the correct address of pt_regs?

The reserved space is fixed(8 bytes in this case), the offset of KSTK_TOP from task is fixed and struct pt_regs also is fixed size. So if you know the task address, you can get the address of struct pt_regs.

Comment: Tanks for your help! With your explanation,I've got it.Your answer is very clear!